# Submit to arXiv failed because compiler doesn't know "tikz/rotate around y"

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, arxiv

I'm trying to submit an article written in tex to arxiv but the compilation fails whereas it works on my laptop.

The error message is

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/rotate around y' and I am
going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.246 \begin{scope}[rotate around y = 70]

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.246 \begin{scope}[rotate around y = 70]

Output written on arxiv1.dvi (4 pages, 76256 bytes).
Transcript written on arxiv1.log.
```

I don't really have a clue about what is not working but to me it looks like it's because they use an older version of the tikz library that doesn't have "rotate around y". Is that right ?

Any hint to make it compile ?

Or do you know a way to do the same thing without "rotate around y" ?

Comment: I would make my `tikzpicture`s into pdfs (either using `standalone` or `\tikzexternalize`) and then include them as usual with `\includegraphics`. This way you don't have to rely on the arXiv compiler to produce them.

Comment: option 2 is to include the relevant `.sty` files in your submission. This is already the [recommended solution](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#wegotem) for version mismatches between the packages on arXiv and (older) versions on the users' machines.

Comment: arXiv will be rebuilding their TeX in the next few months. You might try again after they roll out the new build.